# Mapping Linear Model Fit Over An Arbitrary Number of sets

Tags: functions, function-construction, fitting, functional-style

I have multiple sets of data, and I want to apply Linear Model Fit sequentially to each set of data.  For example, below `tstlst` contains 3 data sets.  Right now I have created a function which will take in the super set, and then apply `LinearModelFit` to each one of the three.

My question is, how do I extend this to work for any number of sub sets?  For example, if `tstlst` were to contain 100 subsets of data then my current approach would be impossible. I want to be able to generalize the function to work for any number of sets.

```
tstlst = { { {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 5} },
{ {10, 11}, {12, 13}, {14, 15}},
 { {100, 200}, {300, 400}, {500, 600}}}

linearModelFitSet[dataset_] := 
{LinearModelFit[dataset[[1, 1 ;; 3,All]],x, x], 
 LinearModelFit[dataset[[2, 1 ;; 3, All]], x, x], 
 LinearModelFit[dataset[[3, 1 ;; 3, All]], x, x]}

linearModelFitSet[tstlst]
```

gives:

```
{FittedModel[1. +1. x],FittedModel[1. +1. x],FittedModel[100. +1. x]}
```

Comment: Use the tool almost every list-processing procedure in Mathematica uses: `Map` (shorthand `/@`), and familiarize yourself with functions of the `#` `&` kind. `LinearModelFit[#, x, x] & /@ tstlst`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a pure [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) and [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) it over the first level of `tstlst` like so:

```
LinearModelFit[#, x, x] & /@ tstlst
```

Now `tstlst` can have as many sets as you like without you having to know how many in advance.